# UITableViewCell populate data in 0, 9, 17, 25 row when only added to row 0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have big problem with my data in tableView.
I added image in indexPath.row == 0 using code:

```
 let business = self.results[indexPath.row]

 if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.timeImage.image = UIImage(named: "greenTime.png")
 }
```

My image is shown when `indexPath.row` is equal to 0, 9, 17, 25 ...

My business `array.count = 40`

Can someone tell where is the problem?

**EDIT**

I can see that my image is added to another indexPath.row when I move my table height.

Comment: Where is this code coming from, cellForIndexPath ?

Comment: You probably reuse the cell, thus the images are being shown in multiple cells. You may want to set the image to nil for the ones you don't need to show.

Comment: yes...because of the reusability of tableview cell...its not maintain state of button

Comment: you should write an `else` for `if indexPath.row == 0`. ideally every if in `cellForRow` method should have an else.

Comment: Great! It works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Akhilrajtr wrote, you should provide an `else`-block. Reason for that being that iOS reuses cells. If you set the image for one cell, that cell moves off-screen and is therefore being reused and the image is not unset it will persist even though you did not explicitly set the image for this indexpath:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    cell.timeImage.image = UIImage(named: "greenTime.png")
} else {
    cell.timeImage.image = nil
}
```

In short, every `if`-block should have an `else`-block where you undo the changes made in the `if`-block.